# How do I expand variables in a string?

Tags: bash

I have two files named `proc` and `env`.

In `proc`:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer $PORT
```

In `env`:

```
PORT=8080
```

I need to echo the following string (don't exec it) without knowing `PORT` in file

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

---

- `export $(cat env)` can help me load `env`.
- `eval $(cat proc)` can help me exec it (which I don't need).
- `${!var}` maybe useful to expand `$PORT`, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could source the `env` file, `export` the `PORT` variable and use `envsubst` to substitute the variable in `proc`.
This is run in a subshell to keep your environment clean.

```
(. ./env; export PORT; envsubst '$PORT' <proc)
```

Output:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have `envsubst`, you can use this little one-liner, which works on any POSIX shell.

```
$ . ./env; eval echo $(cat proc)
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

All caveats about `eval` apply, i.e. you should make sure `proc` is safe to eval without unwanted side-effects. Limitations: will work only with a one line `proc` and may change some white-space between arguments to a single blank.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the follow command:

```
export $(cat env) && eval echo $(cat proc)
```